# Show that $|I_m-AB|=|I_n-BA|$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ an $n\times m$ matrix. Show that 
$$
|I_m-AB|=|I_n-BA|.
$$

I don't know where to start.

Comment: Hint: The determinant is fixed by conjugation by any invertible matrix.

Comment: @Travis Thanks! What does conjugation mean? :P

Comment: @DiaMcThrees : $M\mapsto N^{-1}MN$ is conjugation of $M$ by $N$.

Comment: @Travis : Wouldn't your idea require the matrices to have just as many rows as columns?

Comment: Conjugation by a matrix $P$ is the operation $S \mapsto P^{-1} S P$; it used, for example, when changing bases. In particular, $\det (P^{-1} S P) = \det(P^{-1}) \det(S) \det(P) = (\det P)^{-1} \det S \det P = \det S$.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that the matrices aren't square. In that case you might try to modify this approach by suitably padding $A, B$.

Comment: Also, $A$ and $B$ don't necessarily have full rank.

Comment: It would help to know what the vertical bars on either end of each side are supposed to mean.

Comment: I'm wondering if thinking about the singular value decomposition of $AB$ might help.  I've seen this proved, but at this moment I don't remember how it was done.

Comment: @CharlieFrohman the vertical bars mean determinant

Comment: Bars are ambiguous, they can mean many things. I made it more explicit.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I found [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=N871f_bp810C&pg=PA167&lpg=PA167&dq=show+that+im-ab+%3D+in-ba&source=bl&ots=stZ9k3uUt1&sig=INp4N6otmdCXvXM_NMd8bAdJz8M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XaNNVIX6GIW0yASfrIDIAw&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: So far only I have up-voted the question, although many have commented within only a few minutes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint.

Compute the product of the block matrices
$$ \pmatrix{I_m & A \\ 0 & I_n} \pmatrix{I_m - AB & 0 \\ B & I_n} \pmatrix{I_m & -A \\ 0 & I_n}.$$

This somewhat mystifying calculation can be thought of as performing different "block" row and column operations on the matrix $\pmatrix{I_m & A \\ B & I_n}$, which don't change the determinant.

That is, $$\pmatrix{I_m & -A \\ 0 & I_n} \pmatrix{I_m & A \\ B & I_n}$$ subtracts $A$ times the bottom row from the top row, while
$$ \pmatrix{I_m & A \\ B & I_n} \pmatrix{I_m & -A \\ 0 & I_n}$$ subtracts the first column times $A$ from the second column. The two different ways of eliminating the $A$ lead to two different triangular block matrices with the same determinant.

Comment: +1, Is this the sylvester's determinant criterion?. Is there any other proof other than the block determinant argument?

Comment: I don't know. I haven't heard of that.

Answer (score 8):

Another way of approaching this: define
$$
C = \pmatrix{I&A\\B&I}, \quad D = \pmatrix{I&-A\\0&I}
$$
and note that $\det(CD) = \det(DC)$.

Comment: Thank you as well! I upvoted your answer.

Comment: +1, Is this the sylvester's determinant criterion?. Is there any other proof other than the block determinant argument?

Comment: @dineshdileep if you mean [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_determinant_theorem), then yes. I would think that there must be such proofs, but it's hard to beat block-matrix arguments for brevity.