# If $A$ is a $5×4$ matrix and $B$ is a $4×5$ matrix

Tags: determinant, matrix-equations

What will be the value of
$2(|AB-I_5|+|BA-I_4|) +1 ?$

I am stuck , can't even start the problem, is there some identify which I am missing?

Original question [image: original question]

Comment: @ajotatxe edited

Comment: @vikrant Try some matrices

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan ok

Comment: Try those with $1$s in their diagonal first, they are _generally_ easier.

Comment: The two $I$ need different sizes.

Comment: What do the brackets mean?

Comment: The value of matrix (as we calculate of determinants)

Comment: This is impossible since $AB$ is $5\times 5$ and $BA$ is $4\times 4$

Comment: Check out the [Cauchy-Binet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula).  You will find that $|AB-I_5| = - |BA-I_4|$, so that the original formula always evaluates to 1.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the [Sylvester's determinant identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_identity). Following [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices), suppose $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are matrices of dimension $n × n$, $n × m$, $m × n$, and $m × m$, respectively. When $A$ is invertible, one has
$$
     \det {\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix}}=\det(A)\det(D-CA^{-1}B), 
$$
and if $D$ is invertible
$$
\det {\begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix}}=\det(D)\det(A-BD^{-1}C). 
$$

Using the matrices from your question with the identities above:
$$
\det {\begin{pmatrix}1_4&B\\A&1_5\end{pmatrix}}=\det(1_5-AB)=\det(1_4-BA).
$$

Recall that $\det(cM)=c^n\det(M)$ for a constant $c$ and an $n\times n$ matrix $M$, then 
$$
\det(1_5-AB)=(-1)^5\det(AB-1_5)=\det(1_4-BA)=(-1)^4\det(BA-1_4),
$$
or simply
$$
\det(AB-1_5)=-\det(BA-1_4).
$$

From this last identity, the result to your question is immediate: 1.

There are already many questions about the Sylvester's identity, as the following:

- [Prove that $\det(I-CD)=\det(I-DC) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411664/prove-that-deti-cd-deti-dc?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Sylvester's determinant identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17831/sylvesters-determinant-identity)