# Block matrix proof of Cauchy-Binet

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, alternative-proof, block-matrices

I really like proofs that neatly use block matrices.  For example, [Sylvester's determinant identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_identity) has a nice proofs along these lines such as [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992722/show-that-i-m-ab-i-n-ba/992740#992740), as do the many formulas which use [Schur complements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement).  I was wondering if a proof along these lines would work for [Cauchy-Binet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula).

The formula can be expressed as follows:

> If $A$ is $m \times n$ and $B$ is $n \times m$ (where $m \leq n$), we have
>   $$
> \det(AB) = \sum_{S\in\tbinom{[n]}m} \det(A_{[m],S})\det(B_{S,[m]})
> $$

Where $\tbinom{[n]}m$ is the collection of size $m$ subsets of $[n] = \{1,\dots,n\}$.

Ideally, I'd like to find block-matrices $M,N$ such that $\det(MN)$ is clearly $\det(AB)$, and $\det(NM)$ gives us the other side.

My instinct is to just "pad our matrices out" into square matrices, but look at $M = \pmatrix{A\\0}$ and $N = \pmatrix{B & 0}$ clearly fails.  Perhaps there's something nice with $M = \pmatrix{0&A\\A^T&0}$.

Comment: A proof using block matrices (but not as simple as what you suggest) is given in [D. Laksov, A. Lascoux, P. Pragacz, and A. Thorup, *The LLPT Notes*](http://web.math.ku.dk/noter/filer/sympol.pdf), (APP.1.2) (in the Appendix).

Comment: @Darij thank you for being as incredibly helpful as always. For what it’s worth, I’ve recently encountered a nice proof using exterior products (i.e. anti-symmetric tensor products)